# While loop stop after first iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to create custom while loop when this happen. The whileloop stop itseft after reaching to if statement. It seems like the condition of the If statement executing itself when the value of x inside the expression match the current value of x. Why does this happen? Is there any other way to do this?

```
 function test () {
    var x = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
    while (x.length > 0) {

        console.log(x[0]);
        console.log(x.length)

        if (x.length = 0) {
            x = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
           }
        console.log(x[0]);

        console.log(x.length)

        x.splice(0,1)
     } 
}
```

Comment: = needs to be ==

Comment: = is assignment

Comment: What the comments are saying is that `if (x.length = 0)` should be `if (x.length == 0)`.

Comment: The if-statement doesn't make sense to begin with. Your while-loop will only be entered when the length is more than 0, so `x.length === 0` can never be true.

Comment: Like @Ivar says, you might want your `x.length` check to go after your `splice`.  As were it is, will never equal 0.   Also worth pointing out, even with these fixing, you have created a infinite loop, Not something you should be doing in JS, unless you add some async stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line `if (x.length = 0)` isn't actually checking the length. Because you are only using one equal sign (`=`) instead of two (`==`) or three (`===`), you are actually assigning 0 to the length property of that array, thereby removing all element from the array. After the first iteration, the condition will be false, because there will be no properties in your array, so the length is no longer greater than zero.

Below is your function, corrected. I also moved your `splice()` statement before your last two console logs, so that those logs show the content after the splice, opposed to the previous two console logs. This way, your logs will show the length as zero at the end of the final iteration.

```js
function test() {
    var x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    while (x.length > 0) {
        console.log(`x[0]: ${x[0]}`);
        console.log(`x.length: ${x.length}`);
        if (x.length === 0) {
            x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        }
        x.splice(0, 1);
        console.log(`x[0]: ${x[0]}`);
        console.log(`x.length: ${x.length}`);
    }
}
test();
```